# Camera is scaled strangely on Android device

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I ran my project through Unity Remote and I got this left screenshot with completely messed up scaling, and after that I created new project and simply put four spheres in there and got the same result. Here are two images of that:

[image]

Why does this happen and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Try to adjust the scaling of the camera from the inspector view of the camera and still if there is an issue then you need to add the scaling code of camera which would be attached to the camera. It will help you scale the camera according to your requirements on the run time.If there is issue with the aspect ration of the camera the code is present in below link with full explanation.

### Note :-

Please check there should not be 2 camera attached with one game object because it would also create several problems with the view of the camera .

### Code Example link:-

[The aspect ratio is being adjusted through code](http://gamedesigntheory.blogspot.com/2010/09/controlling-aspect-ratio-in-unity.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that when you try to debug your game using Unity Remote you need to set the Aspect Ratio in the Game Panel to the aspect ratio of your device and then it will give you the right scaling on your phone.

Anyway, if you want to get completely correct picture go for "Build and Run" option.